# react-dnd Delay return to original position in case of failure

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

There is a function, you need to drag to the wrong area, first execute an animation, and then return to the original position.

I searched a lot of information, but I still couldn't find a way.

So hope to get help here. Thank you

This is the video link
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19225489/108029525-8da14c00-7068-11eb-9694-abd5a6badbcf.mp4